# JQuery with HTML5 video detects `play` event but not `ended` event on dynamically created code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video, jquery-events

Recently I've been experimenting with dynamically generated HTML5 tags, and I came up with a problem with binding `ended` event on HTML5 video tag.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650366/2398574) solution found on stack but it works only with `play` event (only on Chrome, does not work on Firefox).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this, is that most HTML5 events do not bubble and jQuery relies on event bubbling for event delegation, which is sad, but you can implement it if you want by using addEventListener:

`//note the third parameter has to be true, it is important to work
document.addEventListener('ended', function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('video')){
        //e.target has ended playing
    }
}, true);`

As an alternative you can use [webshim which implements many HTML5 features](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html#Media) thorugh jQuery.

In case you request a polyfill for `mediaelement`, webshim fixes jQuery's event delegation code for the mediaelement features:

```webshim.polyfill('mediaelement');

$(document).on('play', 'ended', function(){
    //this has ended playing
});

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately your addEventListener doesn't work... I will give a try to webshim now.

Comment: Unfortunately installing webshim would require to many changes since I'm using nodejs and it also I've been requested to write minimal application in terms of number of js files.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have this solution that works on firefox, chrome and safari (IE not tested).

Creating an `audio element` :

`var audio = document.createElement("audio");`

Creating an `eventlistener` to an audio element:

`audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
alert('done');
});`

Comment: it doesn't give any errors, but it won't play either, could you explain how to make it play using your method?

Comment: It plays, but callback doesn't work. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: No... I tried all versions of Chrome including the experimental one, this callback simply doesn't work, bug was reported but it seems like they ignored it. What I did was manual callback, first I check the video duration and I set a callback after this amount of time, this callback will remove the video element. It's not a proper way, but it worked.